# Is it possible to use Power Automate to call a piece of code that duplicates a document?

Tags: javascript, python, power-automate

I am doing a bit of innovation work at the moment for a problem I want to solve. I want to use Power Automate, maybe a flow, that when I add a document to a shared folder such as onedrive, it automatically calls a piece of code that creates another document in a separate folder.

I understand that creating a custom action would be the first step to take, but stripping it back to basics and not specifying folder locations etc - could this be possible using JS or python?